# Do functions when closing and when changing ViewModel - C# using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, mvvm

I have some questions and I'm having some trouble finding answers so I decided to put them here.

**Q1:** I have to make to call a function each time the app closes, like: click exit button and then do something.

**Q2:** I have a menuitemcontrol in the shell viewmodel that controls the ViewModel but on creating them I do some webservices requests, but imagine I delete a friend it is requested that I update the request in the viewmodel, how can I do this calling from other viewmodels?

**EDIT: Scenario -** ShellViewModel that contains HomeViewModel and FriendsViewModel, I accepted a friend in the FriendsViewModel I want that when I click Home the function that fetch the info from the webservice to run again. (If I was doing in code-behind I would use Onclick[Home] > runlogin())

**UpdateQ2:**

```
public FriendsViewModel()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotifyMe);
        au = AuthSingleton.Instance.getAuthUser(); // Singleton that works like a session in the desktop App.
        if (AuthSingleton.Instance.IsAuth == true)
            loadFriends();
    }
    public void NotifyMe(NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
    {
        string notification = notificationMessage.Notification;
        //do your work
        loadFriends();
    }
    #endregion constructors

    public async void loadFriends()
    {

        var response = await CommunicationWebServices.GetASM(au.idUser + "/friends", au.token);
        var fh = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendsHandler>(response);
     }
```

I've decided to use a suggestion from a commenter user to send a message from the second ViewModel to this one to order the update to run again (pretty cool and easy solution), but **it doesn't work** because somehow my singleton is deleted :O

*Message sent:* `MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage("notification message"));`

Best regards,

Comment: Have you considered ICommands/RelayCommands ... you can fire these commands from the UI to the ViewModel and then let the viewmodel handles the actual web service logic.

Comment: @aggietech if I do that where should I call the command? And from which viewmodel? The shell (that contains anothers viewmodels) ?

Comment: Ok - if you're using an IoC (or somekind of container) to register your view models, you should be able to refer them by getting the current instance of that view model

Comment: Re Q2: If you explain what you're trying to achieve step-by-step then you have better chances for an answer.

Comment: @zmechanic see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 - What MVVM framework are you using? All MVVM frameworks I know implement custom commands (aka RelayCommands/DelegatingCommands), so you could attach them to Window events. Another solution would have in your ViewModel an implementation of ClosingRequest event. Something like this:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler ClosingRequest;

    protected void OnClosingRequest()
    {
        if (this.ClosingRequest != null)
        {
            this.ClosingRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in your View you would have:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    ...
    var vm = new BaseViewModel();
    this.Datacontext = vm;
    vm.ClosingRequest += (sender, e) => this.Close();
}
```

If you are using MVVM Light, you can do the following in your ViewModel:

```
public ICommand CmdWindowClosing
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
                (args) =>{
                    });
        }
    }
```

And in your Window:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CmdWindowClosing}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Q2 - Also, this is easy when using a MVVM framework. Most of them implement the Message Mediator pattern. What this mean for your. This mean you can dispatch a message warning "Request needs update" and a receptor binds to that message, implementing something when the message is received. Take a look on this [demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/The-Mediator-Pattern-c2c07b54) from Microsoft

Comment: I'm using MVVM Light. In your example you're using code-behind but I would like not to use that kind of approach? Is possible to do something similiar?  Q2: Nice idea, I completely forgot that possibility. Awesome.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it helps you, please vote +1  :)

Comment: regarding the second answer I'm using a singleton to emulate a session. But when I send the message and the method is run again the singleton is empty? How? I'm not deleting anywhere, and if I put the message in comment the app runs smoothly

Comment: Done. I forget that I have my singleton bulletproof. So I have to the the getAuthUser again :D perfect, thanks for your quicoli.